# HP-15-Notebook-PC shows wifi Adapetr Not Found?

Tags: networking, wireless, hp, ralink

The `rfkill` command shows:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE            SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      hp-wifi      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hp-bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0         unblocked   blocked
```

`lshw -C network` command shows:

```
*-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0f0
   version: 00
   serial: b0:10:41:d5:9b:1b
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.8.0-40-generic firmware=N/A    latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:90710000-9071ffff
```

My Wifi adapter is RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

What will I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Hard blocked: yes This suggests that the wireless switch or key combination (perhaps Fn+F7 or similar) is set to disable the wireless radio. Please find it and switch it. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  I would file against package Linux as this is a kernel issue that should be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of people around the Internet that have trouble with this particular Wireless device. This Wifi adapter is not fully supported by Linux and suffers from the following problems:

- there is only [an experimental driver called rt2800pci](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800pci)
- Ralink does not provide official driver for newer linux kernels
- Some machines experience a Kernel panic when shutting down unless the WiFi is disabled beforehand
- the Bluetooth radio on the card will not work. Period.

The ultimate solution for many people is to do one of the of the following:

- buy a new internal Wifi card which has support in Linux
- buy a WiFi USB dongle which has support in Linux

Comment: So there is no other way to turn on my wifi ☹️

Comment: @RINOJAJ There is a way using a piece of tape to mask a pin on the wifi card, even though the video is for an Intel, all PCIe wifi cards use that pin for the rfkill signal  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzAKcmlaH1M